# Is there a proof that there is no general method to solve transcendental equations?

Tags: analysis, transcendence-theory

Being motivated by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/solving-an-equation-with-irrational-exponents), I was wondering if there is a proof (analogous to the case of Diophantine equations) that there is no general method for solving [transcendental equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation)?  It seems pretty clear, intuitively, that there can be no general method; but the only reason I feel strongly about that is because I can't conceive that transcendental equations have a general method, but Diophantine equations don't.  I was never able to understand the proof for the case of Diophantine equations, so I am not in a position to even know where to begin thinking about this.  Has any work been done on this problem?

Comment: Try encoding the halting of a general turing machine into a transcendental equation.

Comment: Uh, this is an old question, I agree, and there is no sense in posting something after all the answers are well-accepted and voted, but I see that none of the answers below mention that this question essentially asks for the [_Constant problem_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_problem). Just sayin'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The problem is that the term "transcendental function" is absurdly general.  For example, pick a computable bijection between the integers and the set of [Turing machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) and consider the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is $0$ on the integers corresponding to halting Turing machines, $1$ on the integers corresponding to non-halting Turing machines, and smoothly interpolated in between (for example via [bump functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)) such that if $x$ is not an integer then $0 < f(x) < 1$.  Then the problem of determining the solutions to $f(x) = 1$ is equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  (And $f$ is even *smooth*.)

So to get any reasonable answer to this question one must pick a much more specific definition of transcendental function.  One must also specify what it means to find a solution to an equation; is it enough to give an algorithm which will compute it to arbitrary accuracy, or must we get the answer in "closed form" (whatever that means)?  There are a lot of issues here.

Comment: As you point out, the problem is that -- wikipedia article notwithstanding -- there is not an agreed upon definition of "transcendental function".  I was thinking about this question a bit myself and had decided that a transcendental function should be a complex analytic function on $\mathbb{C}^n$ which is not algebraic.  Suppose we ignore the non-algebraic part and just ask whether there is an algorithm to tell whether a system of (recursive?) complex-analytic functions has a common solution.  What do we think about that?

Answer (score 5):

Intuition may be misleading here. In fact transcendental cases are often much easier than the integer Diophantine case. For example below is a table listing the known decidability results in various rings for Hilbert's tenth problem and the full first order theory, excerpted from Bjorn Poonen's interesting paper [Hilbert's tenth problem over rings of number-theoretic interest](http://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/aws2003.pdf)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A general method for solving a given equation $H(x)=0$ is to apply the compositional inverse $H^{-1}$ of $H$: $x=H^{-1}(0)$. In general, $H$ and $H^{-1}$ are correspondences. But often it is possible to split the problem into subproblems where $H$ and $H^{-1}$ are functions.

For applying this method, $H$ and $H^{-1}$ have to be known. That means they have to be in closed form ([Wikipedia: Closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)). "Closed form" means expressions of allowed functions. If an equation is solvable in closed form depends therefore on the functions you allow.

There is a general method for the elementary functions.

The elementary functions are according to Liouville and Ritt those functions of one variable which are obtained in a finite number of steps by performing algebraic operations and taking exponentials and logarithms ([Wikipedia: Elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function)).

The incomprehensibly unfortunately hardly noticed theorem of Joseph Fels Ritt in [[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/) answers which kinds of Elementary functions can have an inverse which is an Elementary function. You can also take the method of
[Rosenlicht, M.: On the explicit solvability of certain transcendental equations. Publications mathématiques de l'IHÉS 36 (1969) 15-22](https://eudml.org/doc/103891).

If $H$ can be decomposed into compositions of algebraic functions and other known Standard functions than $\exp$ and $\ln$, an analog theorem to the theorem of Ritt of [Ritt 1925] could be applied. I hope to prove such a generalization of Ritt's theorem for this class of functions.

Comment: Please stop editing all your old answers and bumping them up to the front page.