# Series solution to Johann Lambert's trinomial.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been researching the series solution to Johann Lambert's trinomial equation, $x^m+px=q$.

The series solution that I have discovered does not converge. Can someone tell me the exact series and explain it? I have read his original analysis in Latin but the analysis for the stated equation is not there.
$x=\frac qp-....$
I am trying to solve a simple equation, $x^4+2x=3$. The obvious solution is $x=1$ and I cannot calculate it with series I discovered. Then I would use polynomial long division and get a cubic, which I would hopefully depress with Cardano's method. This should be a real solution and then I can use the quadratic formula. This is my first attempt at this.

Comment: [This Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial) post may help. Please post the series you found.

Comment: see Szabó and Belkić in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4657862/how-to-solve-a-trinomial-with-a-rational-exponent-xq-x-c-0/4659046#4659046

Comment: That series $$x={p}^{-1}q-{p}^{-5}{q}^{4}+4\,{p}^{-9}{q}^{7} -22\,{p}^{-13}{q}^{10}+140\,{p}^{-17}{q}^{13} +\dots  $$is only for the case $|q^3/p^4| <1$.  You will need a different series to get your answer $1$.

Comment: Use the rational root theorem?

Comment: GEdgar Thank you very much. I reread the appropriate section of Observationes Variae In Mathesin Puram, (m-1)^m p^m is greater than m^m q^m-1. My Latin is rusty. Has this been written in English?

Answer (score 3):

Apply [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem). Taking the multivalued root on both sides can give all complex roots, but for one $x\in\Bbb R$ solution:  $$x^m+ax=b\implies x=\sqrt[m]{b-ax}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(b-ax)^\frac nm\right|_0$$  and [factorial power $n^{(m)}$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html). The radius of convergence was found using the ratio test and software:  $$\boxed{x^m+ax=b\implies x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{b^\frac nm}{n!} \left(-\frac ab\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac nm\right)^{(n-1)},\left|-\frac am\left(\frac b{1-m}\right)^{\frac1m-1}\right|<1}$$  [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E3.2%2B5.4x-9.7%2Cx%3Dsum%5B1%2Fn%21+%28-5.4%2F9.7%29%5E%28n-1%29+9.7%5E%28n%2F3.2%29+factorialpower%28%28n%2F3.2%29%2C+n-1%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C80%7D%5D). As for the asker’s equation:

$$\boxed{x^4+2x=3\implies x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-2)^{n-1}}{3^{\frac{3n}4-1}n!}\left(\frac n4\right)^{(n-1)}=\sqrt[4]3-\frac1{2\sqrt3}-\frac1{24\sqrt[4]3}+\frac7{1152\cdot3^\frac34}+\frac1{432\sqrt3}+\dots=1}$$

which also converges since $\left|-\frac 24\left(\frac 3{1-4}\right)^{\frac14-1}\right|=\frac12<1$

Comment: One may get a closed form for the equation using the [Fox Wright function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) or using Wolfram’s [inverse beta regularized](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463894/how-to-solve-xy-ax-b/4464966#4464966)